# How to reset Windows subsystem for linux bash after modifying it with dotfiles?

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, windows-subsystem-for-linux, dotfiles

[I installed 'dotfile' on my windows 'ubuntu' terminal](https://github.com/rohegde7/dotfiles)

Now I am not able to work with normal commands like 'git'.
Want to know how to reset my bash file to regain the original terminal.

Comment: Possible way: You may make your own file with command `echo abc > ~/.bashrc`. Or create a new user and delete the old one. Git only need `.gitconfig` files.

Answer (score 0):

The original .bashrc, .bash_logout, and .profile files are stored in /etc/skel/.  When a new user is created, these files are copied to the new users home directory.

To restore these files, simply run the following command.

```
cp /etc/skel/.bashrc /etc/skel/.profile ~
```

This will copy the original files to your home directory, overwriting your modified files.